# How to make angular dropdown control (not select) in angular form?

Tags: angularjs, forms, dropdown, dirty-data

I want to use a dropdown button instead of a select-options in a form. I'm using angular, and the problem is:
1. The dropdown should display the name of the selection but the form should submit its Id instead
2. Changes to the dropdown don't make the form dirty

How do I resolve this?

Comment: you can use ng options like `ng-model="obj.arrItem.id" ng-options="arrItem.name for arrItem in arrItems"` while submiting form use value from ng model

Comment: on your select tag do you use ng-model? can you create a fiddle?

Comment: The point is I want to use a dropdown (ul, li) instead of a select... But I want it to behave like a select...

Answer (score 0):

ok, resolved, it appears I had a very small typeo in the dropdown button's ng-if expression, which caused it to always show "None" instead of the selected item from the list. This led me to think that the selection in the form did not propagate to the model..

anyway, here's my working [codepen](http://codepen.io/sagimann/pen/jbgMBz) - I'm using the form field controller's setViewModel to push a value from the dropdown to the hidden input field, and angular takes care of pushing it down to the model while making the form dirty:

```
form.groupId.$setViewValue(group.id);
```

Anyway, it seems like the most elegant way (I could find) to do this (except maybe using a directive to compeltely replace the select input..)

Hope this helps!